# How to get unique array and sum the value of array in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working in wordpress and trying to get order detail, but the problem is i have multiple order with same name and i want to get sum of the quantity of the product with unique name of product, please help.

Here is the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => demo product
            [quantity] => 1
            [total] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => demo product
            [quantity] => 1
            [total] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => demo product
            [quantity] => 1
            [total] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => test 2nd
            [quantity] => 1
            [total] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => 7" DELICIOUS WHITE PIZZA BOX E-FL 1x100
            [quantity] => 1
            [total] => 6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => 1000ml MICROWAVE CONTAINER LIDS 1x250
            [quantity] => 1
            [total] => 19
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => 1000ml MICROWAVE CONTAINER LIDS 1x250
            [quantity] => 5
            [total] => 95
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => 7" DELICIOUS WHITE PIZZA BOX E-FL 1x100
            [quantity] => 20
            [total] => 120
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => 7" DELICIOUS WHITE PIZZA BOX E-FL 1x100
            [quantity] => 20
            [total] => 120
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => 7" DELICIOUS WHITE PIZZA BOX E-FL 1x100
            [quantity] => 20
            [total] => 120
        )

)
```

Below is the PHP code that i tried before, it works but i need sum of quantity also

```
 $final_data[] = array(
        'product_name' => $product_name,
        'quantity' => $item_quantity,
        'total' => number_format($item_total)
 );

 $output_data = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $final_data)));
```

Any solution appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try with this, it will give you an array based on the name of the product that can help you getting the correct value.

```
$new_data = array();
Foreach($data as $key=>$value){
   $new_data[$value['product_name']][] = $value;
}
print_r($new_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
$totalQuantity = array_sum(array_column($array, 'quantity'));
$total = array_sum(array_column($array, 'total'));
```

Hope it will help you

**EDIT**
I am not sure what kind of name you want to give your product as they all seems different to me, so you can make your own logic for that.